# Tweetsharp authorization renders no oauth token

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, tweetsharp

I am trying to implement tweetsharp in my asp.net mvc 3 application but I am running into issues.

I have created a new twitter application with the following settings:

- Application website: http://127.0.0.1:8545/
- Type: browser
- Callback URL: none
- Access Type: read/write

I then used the sample provided on their website with a few minor changes:

```
public ActionResult Twitter()
{
    TwitterService service = new TwitterService("key", "secret");
    OAuthRequestToken requestToken = service.GetRequestToken("http://127.0.0.1:8545/Membership/TwitterOAuth");

    var uri = service.GetAuthorizationUri(requestToken);

    return new RedirectResult(uri.ToString(), false /*permanent*/);
}

public ActionResult TwitterOAuth(string oauth_token, string oauth_verifier)
{
    var requestToken = new OAuthRequestToken { Token = oauth_token };

    TwitterService service = new TwitterService("key", "secret");
    OAuthAccessToken accessToken = service.GetAccessToken(requestToken, oauth_verifier);

    service.AuthenticateWith(accessToken.Token, accessToken.TokenSecret);
    TwitterUser user = service.VerifyCredentials();

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Whenever I runt his code I get redirected to the following twitter URL: https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=?

Anyone experienced this before?

---

EDIT

It appears that issue was with the way the application was setup. Since I did not provide a callback url, the application was automatically saved as a client and not browser application. Once I added a callback url the code worked correctly.

Comment: You should create an answer to your own question instead of the edit. This helped me out a lot and it would be good if it was posted as an accepted answer so people see it quickly.

Comment: Did you register your application to twitter?

Answer (score 5):

It appears that issue was with the way the application was setup. Since you did not provide a callback url, the application was automatically saved as a client and not browser application. Once you added a callback url the code worked correctly.

[From you own question text]